# Do 6 motors require 6 individually-assigned batteries?

Tags: motor, battery

For the Dagu Wild Thumper 6 Wheeled platform, or any multiple motor system, do I really need 1 battery for each motor? Or should I just buy 2 for either side of the platform. In addition, for larger motors like the ones on this platform, how do I deal with the power generated from a coasting motor?

I want to jump into the deep end with robotics, as I already hold all the programming skills, and I realize a platform of this magnitude may be a difficult endeavor.

Recommended motor voltage is 2 – 7.5 Volts, so should one use two 22 Volt batteries for the left and right side, or six 7.5 volt batteries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that platform.  But in general, no, you do not need separate batteries for each motor.

Also in general, if you need 2-7.5V for each motor, then you probably want one honkin' big battery that puts out 7.5V or slightly more.  You could use a 12V battery and take care with your drive commands to never give the motors over 7.5V.

Only if you need to do something odd like connecting the motors in series would you need more voltage.